# Product Description for EMC test

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, emc, layout, sbc

I'm writing a document that should explain about a mini-PC in my company in order to give information for EMC test engineers who don't know the product.

The mini-PC introduces high granularity modular design and parametric enclosure.

[This](https://s3.amazonaws.com/fit-iot/tensor-pc/docs/introduction-to-tensor-pc.pdf) is the product specification file.

I'm intending to make a one page brief overview of the product that could be useful before performing the EMC test and get authorized for FCC mark.

I was wondering what are the product-related parameters, specifications, description that should be in the document in order to give a previous knowledge for the EMC engineers before performing the test.

Here are some aspects that I thought of:

- Power
- Extensions for mini-PC
- different enclosures for the SBC (including dimensions, Height, cooling ribs)
- PCB Specs (number of Layers, diff traces impedance, single traces impedance)

What do you think about these aspects, and can you suggest me more ideas?

Comment: Depends entirely on what EMC test they are to perform.

Comment: It's a test that is performed to get the FCC mark.

Comment: You need to explain everything of relevance that relates to how they should wires the thing up and with what they should connect it to like other equipment (displays, keyboards, other PCs, LANs, ethernet etc.) and power supplies. You probably need to furnish them the precise power supply that is recommended for your product. Anything that is related to how to use it in all its different configurations that you need it testing under is important. Put yourself in their shoes.

Comment: @Xhero39 - Which FCC Mark?  Do you have a document that describes the various EMC requirements that the product has to meet (RE, CE, RS, CS, etc)?

Comment: @SteveSh, I can ask my supervisors and edit the post. Although I can't see why the requirements would help answering my question. my question was what data should I prepare to help making this process faster and efficient. and not what should we do to meet the requirements.

Comment: They will need to know the frequencies of on board oscillators, since they typically test to 10X the highest clock, or until the noise starts rolling off.  The device must be running in the same configuration that it will be running in the field.    You can also just ask the test engineers what they need.

Comment: @crj11 what do you mean "they typically test to 10X the highest clock, or until the noise starts rolling off."? can you explain further while focusing on the part of the test procedure that you're talking about?

Comment: For radiated emissions, they look for harmonics up to 10X the highest fundamental frequency on the device.  If they see that the harmonics are getting smaller and smaller and are not near the limits, they can stop testing before 10X.  Basically for emission testing, they sweep a spectrum analyzer to locate regions of peaks with a broad filter and then zoom in on the spurs (spurious emissions) to measure the exactly frequency and amplitude

Comment: @crj11 Thanks Man, I get it!